# Running code cells sequentially in google colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I want to run the code cells in Google Colab in sequence.

For example:

Cell[1]

```
from catboost import CatBoostRegressor
#do something here
```

Cell[2]

```
clf = CatBoostRegressor(task_type='GPU')
#do some more things here
```

But when I select "Run all" all cells seem to run in parallel, so my code does not work.

When I do the same thing in a Kaggle Kernel it runs perfectly i.e, first cell[1] is executed, and then cell[2] and so on.

I have tried searching for this in Google Colab but failed to come up with an answer.

Comment: There must be another problem in your notebook, since the "Run all" command should work exactly the same as in Jupyter

Answer (score 13):

To run all cells at a time just press `ctrl+F9` or go to runtime menu on top and click `run all` option and all cells run at a time.

If you want to run one by one then just go to `runtime menu` on top and click `run after` option and all cells run one by one. Note one thing that if you want to run from top cell then place cursor on top cell and then start.

Answer (score 2):

Run all does indeed run cells sequentially, e.g.,

[image]

Can you share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem you observe? I suspect the issue is something other than sequential execution.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023, clicking `Runtime` > `Run all` runs all cells in a sequential manner. Just make sure your cells are ordered in the intended order of execution, before hitting `Run all`.